# What is the proper way to code a read-while loop in Scala?

Tags: scala, inputstream, io

What is the "proper" of writing the standard read-while loop in Scala? By proper I mean written in a Scala-like way as opposed to a Java-like way.

Here is the code I have in Java:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
InputStream input = new FileInputStream( "file" );
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int readLen;
while( ( readLen = input.read( buffer ) ) != -1 )
    md.update( buffer, 0, readLen );
return md.digest();
```

Here is the code I have in Scala:

```
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance( hashInfo.algorithm )
val input = new FileInputStream( "file" )
val buffer = new Array[ Byte ]( 1024 )
var readLen = 0
while( readLen != -1 )
{
    readLen = input.read( buffer )
    if( readLen != -1 )
        md.update( buffer, 0, readLen )
}
md.digest
```

The Scala code is correct and works, but feels very un-Scala-ish. For one it is a literal translation of the Java code, taking advantage of none of the advantages of Scala. Further it is actually longer than the Java code! I really feel like I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

I'm fairly new to Scala, and so I'm asking the question to avoid falling into the pitfall of writing Java-style code in Scala. I'm more interested in the Scala way to solve this kind of problem than in any specific helper method that might be provided by the Scala API to hash a file.

(I apologize in advance for my ad hoc Scala adjectives throughout this question.)

Comment: My answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849303 may be helpful.

Comment: @Rex I'd use `Iterator` instead of `Stream`. After all, it _is_ one-shot and not re-usable. Besides, `Iterator` has better memory performance in such tasks.

Comment: @Daniel - Agreed.  I believe that there was some good reason at one point why I used `Stream` before, but I can no longer recall what (and I don't think it remains true anyway).  Regardless, here `Iterator.continually` should be fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on Rex's post that he mentioned:

```
Stream.continually(input.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(md.update(buffer, 0, _))
```

You should replace the var readLen + while {...} lines with it, it produces the same result.

As Rex mentioned, it works with scala 2.8.

Comment: If Stream gives you the willies, you can also just use Iterator.continually.

Comment: When I try it on an InputStream I got from a Process, the foreach method is just called for the first character and then stop. When used with while, I get all the data. Any idea of why?

Comment: how do I get the amount of bytes read from "input.read(...)" to use it in "foreach"?

Answer (score 9):

What Rex Kerr suggests in his comment is the following:

```
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
val input = new FileInputStream("foo.txt")
val buffer = new Array[ Byte ]( 1024 )
Stream.continually(input.read(buffer))
  .takeWhile(_ != -1)
  .foreach(md.update(buffer, 0, _))
md.digest
```

The key is the `Stream.continually`. It gets an expression which is evaluated continually, creating an infinite `Stream` of the evaluated expression. The `takeWhile` is the translation from the `while`-condition. The `foreach` is the body of the `while`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about a curried function?  You 11 lines of Scala code become:

```
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashInfo.algorithm)
val input = new FileInputStream("file")
iterateStream(input){ (data, length) => 
    md.update(data, 0, length)
}
md.digest
```

The `iterateStream` function on line 3, which you could add to a library is:

```
def iterateStream(input: InputStream)(f: (Array[Byte], Int) => Unit){
    val buffer = new Array[Byte](512)
    var curr = input.read(buffer)
    while(curr != -1){
        f(buffer, curr)
        curr = input.read(buffer)
    }
}
```

The ugly duplicated code (where the input is read) ends up in the library, well tested and hidden away from the programmer.  I feel that the first block of code is less complex than the `Iterator.continually` solution.