# Load RSA key in Android/Java generated with OpenSSL?

Tags: java, php, android, openssl, rsa

I have generated a RSA key with PHP (openssl). It workes fine. I used this PHP script to create the keys:

```
$config = array(
"digest_alg" => "sha512",
"private_key_bits" => 2048,
"private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
 );
$keys = openssl_pkey_new($config);
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($keys);
$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
$publicKey = $details['key'];
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, 'private.pem');
file_put_contents('public.der', $publicKey);
```

Now I would like to load the keys (public.der and private.pem) by Android/Java. But I do not know how because of the format of the RSA key. I think the public.der can be in the assets folder (in Android).

I will not store the public key which belongs to the private key on the same device.

**Edit:** The content of the public.der file:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAog/07W7tF/7/tugWy5Fe
cyGMnwbvqYbyPVBJ8/08nZS79sZfROAuxrGz4CJMosCJp9MZdDiwKuLNaQ9Pbayz
mOq6sQ2XpGFDhqrVJJaw3R+oq8dWgtnyZcRs9MvUYVOOltqXV/NVv+X+JECqx8Pz
WiEim6mQtIbcjQ78hZhiC3kZeRIa17YVM/Yagu4tGne/F6gQaMvA+ZSWJIj5mvU1
UOuuCsCsTF5HQbrgWTH7P+ZB3andvPDnih9eNeeplxcVwk1KKdtkn7l1a8t7YYVW
eJtmtfd+sgjeCRDSqh1DNtDTanHOILunGBPZ85bN9dLZ3v5YJeQX4LL5R2jqy3ti
owIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question "[load RSA public Key From File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410770/java-load-rsa-public-key-from-file#answer-19387517)" has a detailed answer to the question how to load DER-encoded keys into Java application.

And question "[Getting RSA private key from PEM BASE64 Encoded private key file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file#7221381)" describes loading PEM-encoded public key into Java application.

Comment: I have already tried this,  but I got this error while reading the public key:java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag. Can you help me? If I add BC as parameter I also get an error: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.io.IOException: cannot recognise object in stream

Comment: And what is content of `public.der`?

Comment: I added the content of the public.der file to the first post.

Comment: This is PEM format. See an answer update.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. This code worked well: 
      String temp = new String(keyBytes);
      String publicKeyPEM = temp.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
      publicKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");


      Base64 b64 = new Base64();
      byte [] decoded = b64.decode(publicKeyPEM);