# ECC public and private keys setters

Tags: cryptography, private-key, public-key, elliptic-curve, java-security

I need to test ECC verification with given public and private keys. I found methods for random keys generation but there are no setters for specific public/private keys. How to set public/private keys as byte array?

```
 byte[] privateKeyBytes = new byte[]{(byte)0x24, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x16, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x90, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x51, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x55, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x1A, (byte)0xA5, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0x55, (byte)0xDB};
 byte[] publicKeyBytes = new byte[]{(byte)0x71, (byte)0x0B, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xF8, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x32, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x8B, (byte)0x20, (byte)0x54, (byte)0xF7, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x26, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x84, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0xC1, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xBF, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x60, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0xAE, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0xA1, (byte)0x43, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x87, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x1F, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x73, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x77, (byte)0x8F};

 KeyPair pair = g.generateKeyPair();
 PublicKey pubKey = pair.getPublic();
 PrivateKey prikey = pair.getPrivate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used for encoded keys:

```
private static PrivateKey generatePrivateKey(KeyFactory factory, byte[] content){
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
    return factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
}

private static PublicKey generatePublicKey(KeyFactory factory, byte[] content) {
    X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(content);
    return factory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
}
```

For unencoded:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp192r1");

ECPrivateKeySpec ecPrivateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(1, privateKeyBytes), spec); 

ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp192r1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
java.security.spec.ECPoint w = new java.security.spec.ECPoint(new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, 0, 24)), new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, 24, 48)));
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(w, params));
```

Answer (score 1):

Public and Private Keys can't be set, because they should be generated.

According to this, you won't be able to set it.

Normally you are able to encode a message and put the public key into the encoding method. Mabye you have an "ImportParameters"-Function like in C#, where you can import a "Key" into the chosen algorithm like RSA.

Edit:
According to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387517/4198052) answer, you can import like this.

I would suggest you generate the keys, store them using a serialisation as JSON or something, so you can import, deserialise and import them in the method again

Comment: I will need them to generate, store and reuse later.

Comment: I would suggest you generate the keys, store them using a serialisation as JSON or something, so you can import, deserialise and import them in the method again.