# How do you encrypt data using a key file in java?

Tags: java, encryption, key, rsa

I'm trying to make a program which uses RSA encryption to encrypt and decrypt data sent to and from multiple computers. I have a folder which stores the public keys of other computers, on my computer. I can't however, seem to load this key file and create a publicKey object which points to it. My current attempt is shown below but I was wondering what methods other people use to do this?

```
      //Returns the key of a friend (given as input)

  public PublicKey getFriendsKey(String friend){
    try{ObjectInputStream friendsKeyInput = new ObjectInputStream(new fileInputStream(programLocation + "/Text Files/encryptionKeys/" + friend + "PublicKey.key"));
    PublicKey friendsKey = friendsKeyInput.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return friendsKey;
  }
```

Comment: Do you understand that the data length is limited to the key length and 100 to 1000 times slower than a symmetric cipher? That data is generally encrypted with a symmetric algorithm such as AES?

Comment: @zaph: actually key length minus at least 11 octets for padding/randomization, although now that keys are mostly (required to be) at least 2048-bit = 256-octet that's relatively less important. OP: tell us how the files were generated, and/or post a sample file (or several if they aren't all similar); if not text, use hex dump(s).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I know but in order to avoid arguments (I failed here) I carefully stated "limited to the key length" which is true. If I take into account padding I have gotten slammed because of raw data capabilities. In the context of my comment I want to indicate that there is a limit on data size for asymmetric encryption and this seemed relevant since the OP states files which may well be greater than key size - padding - whatever, I did not want to get into the padding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using ObjectInputStream? Most probably your key is not a [serializable java object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm). 
See this answer.
[Load RSA public key from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410770/load-rsa-public-key-from-file)

Comment: #11410070 covers SPKI (what Java calls X509EncodedKey) and maybe _some_ other PEM using BC, but not a full X509 cert (or even PKCS7 containing cert), or OpenSSH format publickey which is very different, or (Open)PGP format publickey which is very different, or various of ad-hoc two-number formats.