# JSch giving invalid private key errors for key pair generated by Java

Tags: java, groovy, ssh, public-key-encryption, jsch

I am generating a keypair using Java's `KeyPairGenerator` for use with JGit. However, JSch (the underlying SSH implementation for JGit) keeps giving me *"invalid privatekey"* errors when trying to use the generated private key.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caught: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@bitbucket.hostname/~wlaw/bitbucket_upgrade_test_repo.git: invalid privatekey: [B@4650a407
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@bitbucket.hostname/~wlaw/bitbucket_upgrade_test_repo.git: invalid privatekey: [B@4650a407
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:1)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at Test.run(Test.groovy:95)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@bitbucket.hostname/~wlaw/bitbucket_upgrade_test_repo.git: invalid privatekey: [B@4650a407
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:243)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@4650a407
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:948)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:46)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:442)
    at Test$1.createDefaultJSch(Test.groovy:82)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getJSch(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.createSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.createSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

Here is my code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
keyGen.initialize(4096)
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()

def pub = pair.public as RSAPublicKey
def priv = pair.private as RSAPrivateCrtKey

Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
def publicKeyText = "ssh-rsa " + encoder.encodeToString(keyBlob(pub.publicExponent, pub.modulus))

def id = bitbucket.post {
    request.uri.path = "/rest/ssh/1.0/keys"
    request.uri.query = [user: bitbucketUsername]
    request.body = new JsonBuilder([text: publicKeyText]).toPrettyString()
    response.success { FromServer fs, Object responseBody ->
        responseBody.id
    }
    response.failure { FromServer fs, Object responseBody ->
        println fs.statusCode
        println fs.message
        println fs.headers
        println responseBody
        null
    }
}

def privateKeyText = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
    encoder.encodeToString(priv.getEncoded()) +
    "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

new File("priv").text = privateKeyText
new File("pub").text = publicKeyText

SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host hc, com.jcraft.jsch.Session session) {}

    @Override
    protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
        JSch defaultJSch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs)
        defaultJSch.addIdentity("test", privateKeyText.bytes, publicKeyText.bytes, null)
    }
};

CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
cloneCommand.setURI("ssh://git@$bitbucketHostPort/$project/${repo}.git")
cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
    @Override
    void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory)
    }
})
cloneCommand.call()
```

I did some debugging in the JSch source code, and found that the library is getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on line 228 in com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPairRSA.java.

Is it something I am doing wrong with formatting the keys for JSch? Or could this be a bug in Java's implementation of a KeyPair or perhaps JSch's implementation of parsing them?

Here is an example keypair that is generated by my code:

```
ssh-rsa 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
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
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
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the private key in PEM format.

For that you need BouncyCastle library.

For an example see:
[Java generate RSA key pair and convert to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40862602/850848)