# How to decrypt a JWT with RSA private key

Tags: java, spring, rsa, jwt, jose

We have a remote application sending us a JWT. They used “RSA-OAEP-256” algorithm and “A256CBC-HS512” encryption and our public key to encode the token, and now I am trying to decrypt it and parse the claims. I generated the keys with `openssl rsa -in <myPrivateKey> -pubout -out <myPublicKey>`, then I converted `myPrivateKey` to a .der based on the suggestion of this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410770/load-rsa-public-key-from-file#19387517). Following the guide at [nimbus](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/signed-and-encrypted-jwt), I came up with the following.

```
    @Test
public void testDecryptJwtWithRsa() {
String filename = <myPrivateKey.der>;
String tokenString = <encryptedTokenString>;
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        byte[] encodedPk = pk.getEncoded();
        JWEObject jweObject = JWEObject.parse(tokenString);
        jweObject.decrypt(new DirectDecrypter(encodedPk));
        SignedJWT signedJWT = jweObject.getPayload().toSignedJWT();
        String jsonToken = jweObject.getPayload().toJSONObject().toJSONString();
        System.out.println(jsonToken);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

The java.security.PrivateKey parses correctly, but I am getting an error at `jweObject.decrypt(new DirectDecrypter(encodedPk));` :

`The Content Encryption Key length must be 128 bits (16 bytes), 192 bits (24 bytes), 256 bits (32 bytes), 384 bits (48 bytes) or 512 bites (64 bytes)`

Also, in the debugger, I can see that `jwe.payload` is null, though i don't know if this should be populated before decryption.

Do I need to generate the key differently, or is there another step that I have omitted? Do I need to specify the algorithm somewhere, or use a different decryptor method/class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, I was using the methods for decrypting with symmetric keys rather than public/private. The following handles decryption successfully and allows me to view the claims.

```
    @Test
public void decryptBlazemeterJwt() {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        EncryptedJWT jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(tokenString);
        RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(pk);
        jwt.decrypt(decrypter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```