# How to verify JWT signature using a token and public key in Java

Tags: java, jwt

I have a token in the form of a string and I downloaded the public cert and created a public key out of it as follows.

But I'm not sure how proceed for verification with just this much info.

I found solutions for C# and .NET but not for Java.
Please note I don't have the jks file or private key.

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("d://public.crt");
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
    PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

Answer (score 6):

To verify a JWT in Java using Auth0 library (com.auth0:java-jwt):

1. Retrieve the algorithm the key has been signed with, for example:

   ```
   // Load your public key from a file
   final PublicKey ecdsa256PublicKey = getPublicKey(...);
   final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.ECDSA256((ECPublicKey) ecdsa256PublicKey, null);
   ```
2. Verify its signature using the corresponding algorithm:

   ```
   final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode("J.W.T[...]");
   // Will throw a SignatureVerificationException if the token's signature is invalid
   algorithm.verify(decodedJWT);
   ```

Comment: It's not clear how to getPublicKey

Comment: Loading a public key is not part of the question here. See this thread if you want guidance on loading a public key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387517

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this to verify JWT

```
try {
        DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(jwt); // your string
        JwkProvider provider =  new JwkProviderBuilder(new URL("JWKS URL")).build();
        Jwk jwk = provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);

        Verification verifier = JWT.require(algorithm);
        verifier.build().verify(decodedJWT);
    } catch (JWTVerificationException | JwkException | MalformedURLException e) {
        // throw your exception
    }
```

`JwkProviderBuilder` can be expensive, so if you are using Spring, you can extract it as another method and annotate it with `@PostConstruct` to optimise.

Comment: I have tried this, program is tuck at line "provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId())"

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Are you sure the JWT or the JWKs URL you are passing is correct?

Comment: can you specify the libraries please?

Answer (score 0):

A working example with RSA key is as given below:

```
/* Verification of JWT */
try {
    String token = "some-token";
    String publicKey = "some-key";
    
    //Convert public key string to RSAPublicKey
    byte[] publicKeyByteArr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyByteArr));

    //If the token has an invalid signature, JWTVerificationException will raise.
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(rsaPublicKey, null);
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                //.withIssuer("auth0")
                .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
    DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

}catch(InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | JWTVerificationException e) {
    logger.info("JWT verification is failed");
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

It's obvious but please note that token and publicKey are arbitrary.

Comment: package you are using?

Answer (score -3):

If you ask about JSON WebToken, You can follow below code sample:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;

//Sample method to validate and read the JWT
private void parseJWT(String jwt) {

    //This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as expected)
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser()         
       .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(apiKey.getSecret()))
       .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
    System.out.println("ID: " + claims.getId());
    System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
    System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
    System.out.println("Expiration: " + claims.getExpiration());
}
```

For further reading, you can visit Click [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-java-create-verify)

Comment: What object is apiKey and how do I fetch it's secret given that I have only a public key cert file.

Comment: apiKey is object of com.stormpath.sdk.api.ApiKey, which is used for holding apikey.

String path = "resources/.stormpath/apiKey.properties";

ApiKey apiKey = ApiKeys.builder().setFileLocation(path).build();

Comment: This is not answering what the user asked. Verify using secret key is using HS256 (hmac) while verifying using public key is RS256.