# RSA algorithm on swift and java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I need to generate public/private key for RSA algorithm on IOS device and send public key to server with encrypted text. Server must read public key and decrypt user message.

I have code on swift:

```
 func generateKeys(){
    var publicKey: SecKey?
    var privateKey: SecKey?

    let publicKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject, kSecAttrApplicationTag:"publicTag".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject]
    let privateKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject, kSecAttrApplicationTag:"privateTag".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject]

    var keyPairAttr = [NSObject: NSObject]()
    keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeyType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
    keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 4096 as NSObject
    keyPairAttr[kSecPublicKeyAttrs] = publicKeyAttr as NSObject
    keyPairAttr[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs] = privateKeyAttr as NSObject

    _ = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)

    var error:Unmanaged<CFError>?
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey!, &error) {
            let data:Data = cfdata as Data
            let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
            print("public base 64 : \n\(b64Key)")
        }
        if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(privateKey!, &error) {
            let data:Data = cfdata as Data
            let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
            print("private base 64 : \n\(b64Key)")
        }
    }
    let encrypted = encryptBase64(text: "test", key: publicKey!)
    let decrypted = decpryptBase64(encrpted: encrypted, key: privateKey!)

    print("decrypted \(String(describing: decrypted))")

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}


func encryptBase64(text: String, key: SecKey) -> String {
    let plainBuffer = [UInt8](text.utf8)
    var cipherBufferSize : Int = Int(SecKeyGetBlockSize(key))
    var cipherBuffer = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:Int(cipherBufferSize))

    // Encrypto  should less than key length
    let status = SecKeyEncrypt(key, SecPadding.PKCS1, plainBuffer, plainBuffer.count, &cipherBuffer, &cipherBufferSize)
    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
        print("Failed Encryption")
    }

    let mudata = NSData(bytes: &cipherBuffer, length: cipherBufferSize)
    return mudata.base64EncodedString()
}

func decpryptBase64(encrpted: String, key: SecKey) -> String? {
    let data : NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: encrpted, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let count = data.length / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
    var array = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
    data.getBytes(&array, length:count * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

    var plaintextBufferSize = Int(SecKeyGetBlockSize(key))
    var plaintextBuffer = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:Int(plaintextBufferSize))

    let status = SecKeyDecrypt(key, SecPadding.PKCS1, array, plaintextBufferSize, &plaintextBuffer, &plaintextBufferSize)

    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
        print("Failed Decrypt")
        return nil
    }
    return NSString(bytes: &plaintextBuffer, length: plaintextBufferSize, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
}
```

This code returns public key in PKCS1. I found the library: [SwCrypt](https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt.)
This code helps me to convert PKCS1 into PKCS8 and read public key with java

```
SwKeyConvert.PublicKey.pemToPKCS1DER(publicKeyPEM)
```

But I can't decrypt user message. Can you help me with message decryption? I wrote small unit test.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class TestExample {
    String publicKeyContent = "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";
    String encryptedMessage = "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";

    @Test
    public void encryptTest() throws Exception {
        PublicKey publicKey = convertPublicKey(publicKeyContent);
        assertNotNull(publicKey);

        String s = decryptString(publicKey, encryptedMessage);
        assertNotNull(s);
    }

    private PublicKey convertPublicKey(String publicKey) throws RSAAlgorithmException {
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            //generate public key
            byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RSAAlgorithmException("Unable to generate public key from string " + publicKey + " . " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String decryptString(PublicKey publicKey, String value) throws Exception {
        byte[] decodedBytes;
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            decodedBytes = c.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error = " + e);
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return new String(decodedBytes);
    }
}
```

I have next error:

```
java.lang.Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 512 bytes
```

Comment: First try and create a symmetric implementation. Just showing three lines without any debugging or error indication is basically asking us to do your work for you. Try and create a MCVE!

Comment: Using my example you will get private/public key and java, copy this public key to java and encrypted message.

Comment: For decryption you need the private key. But with just 3 lines of Java, where the key isn't loaded, I think you just copied the lines from somewhere and then asked for a solution. You say you cannot decrypt: what error message are you getting?

Comment: I added more details to question

Comment: Interesting, I thought that the public key encryption was a typo, as you also mentioned PKCS#8, which is the format for the private key. However, you cannot decrypt RSA with a public key. Encryption is with the public key, decryption with the private key.

Comment: Really. Thank you. Java can read PKCS#8 format so I converted my generated in swift public ket to PKCS#8 can I transform public key in java? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410770/load-rsa-public-key-from-file

Answer (score 1):

In an asymmetric cryptosystem, you have a **key pair** consisting of both a *public* and a *private key*.

You encrypt with the public key and you decrypt with the private key. The public key can be shared (publicly) with other parties, enabling them to send you encrypted messages. The private key is kept secret so that only you can decrypt messages encrypted with your public key.

You normally don't encrypt messages directly with RSA, since the message has to be shorter than the modulus and it might have security implications. What you do instead is, you generate a random key for a symmetric encryption scheme, for example AES-256-CTR (or AES-256-GCM if you need authentication in addition to secrecy), encrypt the message with the symmetric encryption scheme, encrypt the key for the symmetric cipher with the asymmetric encryption scheme and send both the (asymmetrically) encrypted key and the (symmetrically) encrypted message to the receiver.

The receiver will first use his/her private key to decrypt the key for the symmetric encryption scheme, then use that to decrypt the actual message. This is sometimes referred to as "hybrid encryption" and it enables the message to be (more or less) arbitrarily long.

So, what you have to do is the following.

1. You have to generate a key pair for the **receiver** of the encrypted message. Therefore, if your communication is one-way (iOS device sends data to server, but no data ever comes back), you need to generate a key pair for your server only. If your server needs to talk back, you need to generate a key pair for your client as well.
2. In order to send an encrypted message to the server, the client needs to have the public key of your server. Therefore, you have to somehow transfer it there. The problem is that this transfer needs to be secure, otherwise an attacker may impersonate the server, present you **his/her** public key instead (for which he/she knows the private counterpart), intercept all traffic, decrypt it with his/her private key, re-encrypt it with the server's public key and pass it on to the server. This is called a **man in the middle attack** and enables the attacker to intercept (and possibly manipulate) all communication between you and the server. Therefore, your best choice might be not to **exchange** public keys at all but rather to **embed** them into the application. This will prevent man in the middle attacks, as long as the application code can be shared by an authenticated means.
3. When you want to send a message to the server, generate a random symmetric encryption key (with a **cryptographically secure random number generator** - this is **not** your language's default "random" function), encrypt the message with it and an appropriate symmetric encryption scheme, which you choose according to your requirements (e. g. authentication required? then use AES-GCM - only secrecy required? then use AES-CTR). Most encryption schemes also require a **random** (unpredictable) **initialization vector** which you also generate with a CSPRNG and have to send along to the receiver since it's required for decryption, but needs not be kept secret.
4. Encrypt the key for the symmetric encryption scheme with an asymmetric encryption scheme and the server's public key. RSA-PKCS1 is "dated". I'd try to use RSA-OAEP instead since it has more desirable security properties. Send the encrypted key to the server.
5. The server decrypts the key for the symmetric encryption scheme with the asymmetric encryption scheme and his **private key** (which is kept **secret**). Then it decrypts the message with the symmetric encryption scheme.

Since most of this is complicated and a lot of subtle details can lead to security breaches, I'd suggest you do **not** implement this yourself. I'd suggest you just use TLS (possibly with a restricted parameter set) and implement your own certificate validator where you compare the server's public key to a known-good value to get rid of the entire PKI stuff, which costs money and also is not very secure in the first place. At least, that's how I would do it.

Alternatively, if you want to roll out your own, "proprietary" protocol, you can try to use one of the more "developer friendly" cryptographic libraries, especially *NaCl*. This abstracts away a lot of the "gory details" and chooses lots of sane defaults for you, which cannot be overridden, all of which makes it a lot harder to implement insecure protocols.

Keep in mind this is **not** to say you're "too dumb". It's just the proper way of doing these things. When it comes to crypto, the less "DIY", the better. The more widespread the crypto is, that you use, the more it gets reviewed and the quicker flaws will get fixed, so using something like *NaCl*, which is used in thousands of applications, is pretty neat. As long as other *NaCl* applications are secure, your application is (probably) secure as well. When a breach is found, *NaCl* will get updated, you just update the library in your application and are automatically safe, so you're left with (almost) no need for internal review and patching and your windows of vulnerability will (usually) be short.