# How to load public RSA key in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, openssl

I get a public key string from a json as :

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    ....
 -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I get this error when I load it :

```
com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key
```

I need it to be a pkcs8 in order to load it, is there any solution besides using a third library ?

I load PKCS8 like this:

```
   override suspend fun loadPublicKey(key: String): PublicKey {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val readString = key.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")

            val encoded = Base64.decode(readString, Base64.DEFAULT)

            KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
                .generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded))
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you load it, exactly? Please post your code.

Comment: @Alexey Soshin I edited it.

Comment: Check out this thread, maybe it will help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410770/load-rsa-public-key-from-file