# sendEmail with attachment in Lift on CentOS linux

Tags: linux, scala, lift

I'm trying to upload a file and send it as an attachment with an email. My
 code is working on windows OS but when I try to run it on Linux server, it
 creates the file but cannot attach it to the email. Any idea why this
 happens under Linux server? 
Below is my code:

```
  class ClientUpload extends Logger {

object excelFile extends RequestVar[Box[FileParamHolder]](Empty)

private val aRandomTargetFile = Random.nextLong().toString + ".xls"

 private def importExcel(name:String,sheetName:String): List[String] = {
println("import excel sheet="+sheetName+"name="+name)
var response : List[String] = Nil
var currRow = 0
if(sheetName == "Form")
           currRow = firstRow
else if(sheetName == "Form2")   
           currRow = firstRow+1
if(currRow != 0){
try{
   var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(name))
    val sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName)

    try{

        var endOfSheet_? : Boolean = false
        val style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index)
        style.setFillPattern(1)
        while (!endOfSheet_?) {
           val row = sheet.getRow(currRow)
           println("row="+row.getCell(0))
           if (row != null &&
                row.getCell(0) != null &&
                row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue() > 0 ) {

              info("Processing row "+ currRow)                

            }
            else
            {
                 endOfSheet_? = true
            }
           currRow = currRow + 1
        }

      }catch {
            case e: Exception => { }
            case _ => { response = "Problem at cell 0 of row " + currRow :: response }
    }


      var fos: FileOutputStream = null;

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/"+aRandomTargetFile));

    workbook.write(fos);
} catch {
     case e: IOException => { response = "Problem opening or closing the excel sheet : " + e.getMessage() :: response }
     case _ => { response = "Problem opening or closing the excel sheet : " + sheetName :: response}
}
}
   response.reverse
}
def render ={
def process() {

  excelFile.is match {

  case Empty => S.error(S.?("upload.error.missing"))

  case Full(exf) => {
    var  result : List[String] = Nil
      info("Proccessing excel file")
      info("Meme type="+exf.mimeType)
     val basepath = "/tmp/" 
     val aRandomTargetFile = Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + ".xls"

      val oFile = new File(basepath, aRandomTargetFile) 

      val output = new FileOutputStream(oFile)
      output.write(exf.file)
      output.close()

      result = result ++ importExcel(oFile.getPath(),"Form")


      if(!result.isEmpty)
        S.error(<li>{"Found the following problems:"}</li>++result.map(r => <li>{r}</li>))
      else
        sendEmail() &
        S.notice("Successfully sent your upload.") 

    }
   case _ => S.error(S.?("upload.error"))
  }
}

uploadExcel &
"type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
}


 def uploadExcel: CssBindFunc = {

(S.get_?, excelFile.is) match {
  case (true, _)  => "name=file" #> SHtml.fileUpload(s => excelFile(Full(s)),("class"  -> "btn btn-file"))
  case (_, Empty) => "name=file" #> SHtml.fileUpload(s => excelFile(Full(s)),("class" -> "btn btn-file"))
  case (false, _) => "name=file" #> SHtml.link(S.hostAndPath + "/tmp/" + aRandomTargetFile,() => Unit , <span></span>) &   
  "type=submit" #> SHtml.ajaxButton("Upload another file", ()=>S.redirectTo("clientupload"))  
}
}

def sendEmail(): JsCmd = {


      val body = sroiEmailBody
    val fileLoc="/tmp/"+aRandomTargetFile
    println(fileLoc)
val msg =  
  for ( bytes <- LiftRules.loadResource(fileLoc) )
 yield XHTMLPlusImages(<p>Dear user,<br/><br/>The enclosed file has been sent for review</p>,PlusImageHolder(aRandomTargetFile, "text/csv", bytes) )


 msg match {
case Full(m) =>

      Mailer.sendMail(
            From(emailFrom),
            Subject("Upload"),
            To(emailTo), 
            CC(userEmail),
            PlainMailBodyType(body),
            m)

         case _ =>Alert("There was a problem !") 
  }

JsCmds.RedirectTo("clientupload")        


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that works in windows, but I think `LiftRules.loadResource` uses the classloader to retrieve files relative to the webapp (and /tmp/ would not be in that). Have you tried reading the file directly? Perhaps with one of these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/how-to-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-scala

Comment: actually if instead of Random file I use a specific name then the attachment works but if I upload a new different file it creates it in the tmp folder but sends an old file in the email. It means that it can read and overwite the file. I think the old file remains in the memory!

Comment: Can you show the whole code? `sendEmail` is outside of `process` AFAICT so the former must not be using the `aRandomTargetFile` defined in the latter