# how to read a file as a bytestring in a scala?

Tags: scala

I want to make TCP-IO in scala. And the data type will be bytestring.
Then, I want to read a file as a bytestring type in a scala, intellij, akka 2.3.14.

Comment: What is a byte string? Do you mean a String or a byte array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file as a byte array in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/how-to-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-scala)

Comment: @Daenyth OP is referring to [akka.util.ByteString](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/#akka.util.ByteString)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're talking about `akka.util.ByteString` you could make 1 ByteString for the entire file:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import scala.io.Source

def fileToByteStr(filename : String) : ByteString = 
  ByteString(Source.fromFile(filename).mkString)
```

Or, if you want 1 ByteString for each line in your file which lazily remains "on the plate" until the Iterator is drained:

```
def fileToMultipleByteStr(filename : String) : Iterator[ByteString] = 
  Source.fromFile(filename)
        .getLines()
        .map(ByteString.apply)
```

If you want the data in memory you can drain the Iterator to a Seq:

```
val memoryHog = fileToMultipleByteStr("foo.txt").toSeq
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get `Source[ByteString, _]` for Akka Streams, I'd recommend:

```
val source = FileIO.fromPath(filename)
```

Comment: Worked as charm for `HttpEntity`, when I'm posting a file using akka-http. Thank you!\