# How to read a resource file to a byte array in scala?

Tags: scala

I just want to read file in resource and get a byte array? Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360977/how-to-read-files-from-resources-folder-in-scala?rq=1 (that one tries to read lines instead of bytes, but maybe you can adapt it, for example by combining it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/how-to-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** this requires Java 9+

I use the following to read a file in my resources as byte array:

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/file-in-resource-folder").readAllBytes()
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in [How to read a file as a byte array in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/), the following fragment should do the trick:

```
def slurp(resource: String) = {
  val bis = new BufferedInputStream(getClass.getResource(resource))
  try Stream.continually(bis.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
  finally bis.close()
}
```

Comment: This approach is very slow and heavy on CPU, because it reads the file byte by byte, one byte at a time.