# Memory efficient way to iterate on a big range

Tags: scala, memory-efficient

I want to compare two really big data sets byte-by-byte in a specific range.

So for example I'd have one 0x80000000 bytes long file and another 0xffffffff bytes long file.
And lets say I'd like to compare these two files in a specific range byte-by-byte from 0x1000 to 0x7200000.

If it was a smaller range I'd probably go for `until`, but now since it's a much bigger range `until` would be pretty inefficient memory wise.

How would one implement such basic operation in a functional and memory efficient way?

Comment: `until` has fixed memory usage, so how is it inefficient for larger ranges?

Comment: When using `until` I get a GC overhead not enough memory error

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you seem to be talking about the difficulty of loading all the data in the two files into memory at once. That's not a problem since Scala supports reading from files lazily line-by-line. I'm not sure how to read from the file byte-by-byte though.

Comment: This stackoverflow post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/how-to-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-scala Now you just need to read from the file lazily.

Comment: You need to post your code and show how you are reading the files and how you are using `until` to compare them.