# Converting FileInputStream to Array[Byte] Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, fileinputstream

I would convert a FileInputStream to Array[Byte] in Scala 2.13 without using Apache Commons IO. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)

Comment: I guess you could make it a string and then do getBytes on it? I've personally had this same issue some days ago and I juset went with Apache Commions IO solution. val byteArray = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputFiles)  , why do you not wanna use that?

Comment: This also might work? val bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))
val bArray = Stream.continually(bis.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray  taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598135/how-to-read-a-file-as-a-byte-array-in-scala